# How to add another action button in prestashop 1.6.1.3 back end list/grid view panel

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

How to add another action button in prestashop back end list /grid view pannel.
I want do to export functionality one with xls and one with csv .So I need  to add a new button so which file I need to add or look into.
Also is there a way to remove the add button , because I just want to display the data so there is no need of that add button.

[image]

Comment: I've never found a pretty solution for this, but I don't really want to delve into the Helper classes either. What I usually do, is stick a bit of JS (that will add the button) at the end of the `renderList()` function, where you call `return parent::renderList().$myJSbithere;`

Comment: Do you want to add in all the admin controllers?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add it just put code in controller __construct function

```
public function __construct()
{ 
    $this->toolbar_btn['print'] = array(
       'href' => '{your button action}',
       'desc' => $this->l('{your button name}'),
       'remove_onclick' => true
    );
}
```